# Dimension of a variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the underlying topological space of a scheme (/ variety, not necessarily irreducible). We define the dimension of $X$ as the supremum of all integers $n$ such that there exists a chain of distinct irreducible closed subset of $X$ as follows : $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset...\subset Z_n$.

Now assume that we can write $X:=X_1 \cup..\cup X_r$ ($X_i$'s are subspaces) and we also have $\text{dim}(X_i) <m$ for all such $i$. Does it necessarily follow that $\text{dim}(X) <m$?

In other words, my question is: Can it happen that $X:=X_1 \cup..\cup X_r$ is a disjoint union of finitely many subspaces of $X$, then $\text{dim}(X) > \text{max}\{\text{dim}(X_i\}$?

Do we need any extra assumptions to conclude this? (e.g. the union has to be disjoint...etc..)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement is true if the $X_i$ are open, see Liu Remark 2.5.6. For a counterexample, consider the spectrum of a DVR, e.g. $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}_p=\{(0),(p)\}$.

Comment: @Douglas Molin,  Thanks for the counterexample and the reference. Instead of $X_i$'s being open, can we give some other condition on $X$ so that the result is still true?

Comment: @DouglasMolin, One thing about your counterexample, $(o)$ is an open point which has dimension same as Krull dimension of $\mathbb Z_p$ that is $1$ and $(p)$ as a closed point has dimension $0$. So both of them has dimension $<2$ and $\text{Spec}(\mathbb Z_p)$ also has dimension $<2$. So where exactly is the contradiction? (Please correct me if the line of argument is wrong).

Comment: Both $\{(0)\}$ and $\{(p)\}$ are singletons, hence they have dimension 0!

Comment: @DouglasMolin, Isn't $(0)$ an open set? Note that $(0) \subset (p)$ and its closure $\bar(0)=\text{spec}(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Comment: Indeed, $\{(0)\}$ is open in $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}_p$, but it is still of dimension $0$ as it is a point $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin, I understand it now. It's in some sense discrete situation. Can we say something if $X$ is a standard projective variety. Then I think $X_i$'s are locally closed and the union is disjoint meaning $\text{dim}(X)=\text{Sup}\text{dim}(X_i)$. Can locally closedness be relaxed to retain the same result since we have finitely many $X_i$'s?

Comment: If $X_i$ are closed then this is true. So if you know that $\dim X_i = \dim \overline{X_i}$ then you can replace each $X_i$ by $\overline{X_i}$.